Expo with Threejs: RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties
When loading an OBJ model into a Threejs scene in an Expo app, it can fail with the error:

RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties

Is might be because the OBJ is too complex for the JS engine. Tried hermes, jsc, v8 but the same limit was hit when using all of them.
The loader used is imported by
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";

Is there a way to raise the "196607 properties" limit in Expo's JS engine?

Sounds like https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/139. At any rate, this isn't an error that V8 throws -> this isn't a V8 question, so dropping the "v8" label.
